# How can I view the contents of a web page without running malicious code?

Tags: web-browser, linux, malware

I received a strange email which has some strange URL in it.  I would like to know what is "behind" the url, but without the risk of running anything malicious.

How can see the contents of the URL, the web page, without running malicious code?
I am on a Linux machine.

Comment: Virtual machine, Live CD, wget... so many options.

Comment: Use http://www.phishtank.com/ They'll proxy it for you and display it statically (as a JPEG) so you can look at it without risk.

Answer (score 2):

You can try doing that using [`wget`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?wget)

```
wget -O test.txt http://the-url.com/you-are-trying-to-check
```